# adding [Required] to base class IdentityUser

Tags: c#

`MyUser` Class inherits from `IdentityUser<int>`. 
I do want to add the validation attribute `[Required]` to the Email Property. As the Email property is defined in the base class `IdentityUser` I may not set `[Required]` as usual. Is it possible to do this for example in the constructor of `MyUser` class and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have direct answer to your question, you could use `new` modifier to override base class property

```
class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public new string Email { get; set; }
}
```

But I would recommend to move this logic to a custom validator and create users through `UserManager`, since later you might want to have more complicated validation logic.

```
class UserValidator : IIdentityValidator<User>
{
    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(User user)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new IdentityResult(new string[] { "Email is required" }));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Example of creating new user

```
var userManager = new UserManager<User, string>(new UserStore<User>(db));

userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator();

var result = userManager.Create(new User());

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // user was created
}
else
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        // process error message
    }
}
```